# コマンドプロンプトでWindowsPCのカメラを立ち上げ指定場所に保管する方法

Tags: windows-10, camera

コマンドプロンプトでWindowsPCのカメラを立ち上げ指定場所に保管する方法を探しています。

使用OS:Windows10
下記方法にてカメラの起動まではわかったのですが、保管場所やファイル名の指定がわかりません。

### 何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

試した方法

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" "microsoft.windows.camera:"
```

とコマンドプロンプトに打鍵するとカメラが立ち上がります。
　↓
録画ボタンを押す
　↓
`C:\Users\ユーザ名\Pictures\Camera Roll`に動画ファイルが保管される

この方法では動画の保存場所もファイル名も指定ができません

Answer (score 1):

解決策ではないし、自分で確認してもいないのですが、ちょっとした情報として。

@WESUEKさんと同様の情報を解説されている記事がありますが、
この記事にもフォルダを変更する情報は無いですね。
[Windows 10のMicrosoft Storeアプリをコマンドラインやバッチから起動する](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1810/19/news038.html)

起動時に任意の場所を指定する方法は不明ですが、フォルダを変更したり追加することは可能なようです。
ただし自分では確認していませんが。

マイクロソフトの公式のサポート情報です。
[Windows 10 で見つからないカメラ ロールを修復する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/13756/windows-10-fix-missing-camera-roll)

> 新しい画像やビデオの保存場所を変更する
>   新しいカメラ ロール フォルダーを作成する

英語サイトに載っていた裏技的なフォルダ変更のやり方です。
[How to Move or Remove Camera Roll and Saved Pictures folders in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/move-remove-camera-roll-saved-pictures-folders)

上記裏技に類似で英語版マイクロソフトのフォーラムに載っていた情報です。
[Window 10 Camera app - need to change save location](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/window-10-camera-app-need-to-change-save-location/631257d7-c03d-4967-b1cf-7940cea3b6c7)
回答の中に、こんなのがありました。

> Keith A. Miller Replied on June 22, 2018
>   Let me say upfromt, I use a standalone machine so am unable to experiment with network redirection.
>   But when the Camera Roll folder's location is changed, a new registry value is created under:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
>   The value name would be: {AB5FB87B-7CE2-4F83-915D-550846C9537B}
>   and its data would be the path to your Camera Roll folder.
>   You might check to see if these values exist on both the working and non-working machines.
>   Keith

Google翻訳したものです。

> さて、私はスタンドアローンのマシンを使っているのでネットワークリダイレクションを試すことはできません。
>   ただし、Camera Rollフォルダの場所が変更されると、新しいレジストリ値が次の場所に作成されます。
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
>   値の名前は次のようになります。{AB5FB87B-7CE2-4F83-915D-550846C9537B}
>   そのデータは、Camera Rollフォルダへのパスになります。
>   これらの値が稼働中のマシンと稼働していないマシンの両方に存在するかどうかを確認してください。
>   キース

Comment: アプリ内でコマンドを実行して生成された動画ファイルを取得したかったんですが、無理そうですね。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @WESUEKさん、自分で作るという手もあります。そのものではないでしょうが、ここにサンプルソースが [Microsoft/Windows-Camera](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Camera), ここに詳細な解説が [カメラ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera), そしてXBox Oneですが、UWPでのコマンドライン引数の扱いが [引数を受け取る](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps#accepting-arguments) あります。